# Upgrade SharePoint 2007 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I have a need to upgrade our SharePoint server from 2007 to 2013. I have read lots of articles for this migration but I still have some confuses about that. 
Someone can give me some suggestions for this.

Below are my current situation

- We have a Production server which using SharePoint 2007, now we have to upgrade this to SharePoint 2013 because of no support from Microsoft for 2007 version.
- We cannot do that on Production environment because we don't know when migration process finished. So there is a NEW server for doing this. After upgrade completed, we will stop current Production server and use this NEW server.

Here are what I need to do :

1. Move data to a new Database Server (DONE) - we are using SQL Server 2012 for our current SharePoint 2007
2. Move current Web app to our NEW SharePoint server (the same version 2007 with current server) to prepare for upgrade process ?
3. Upgrade SharePoint on this new server to 2010 version. I must install SP 2010 manually OR this is automatic step by using a function in current SP 2007 ?
4. After upgrade to 2010, we will upgrade it to 2013 by doing the same steps as from 2007 to 2010. The same question as step 3.

Thank you in advance for your help/suggestion.

Comment: How about asking on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ . I think you will find more helpfull answers there.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will do that but I still put my question here with hope someone can help me

Comment: I have put this question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com as Alex's advice. And I got answer from there. Here is the link if you are interested http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137533/upgrade-sharepoint-2007-to-2013